# PHP failed to open stream ao tentar incluir pasta superior

Tags: php

Estou com um problema no meu PHP que não sei o que está acontecendo.

Atualmente, sempre que eu vou voltar uma pasta em algum diretório eu uso `./` 
por exemplo: "./javascript/jquery.js"

Não sei porque esta acontecendo isso, porque a maneira correta de voltar pastas seria `../javascript/jquery.js` e isso está atrapalhando em alguns processos. Quando vou usar include também uso `include_once("./model/Produto.php")` e quando vou chamar esse include em outro lugar ele da o erro  **failed to open stream: No such file or directory** porque está ./ e não ../

Existe alguma forma de corrigir isso? Lembrando que sempre que meu index.php usa o `.htaccess` no meio da página que usa um `$_GET` que pega o que foi digitado na url e dá um `include_once("caminho/arquivo.php")`, isso pode influenciar em algo?

Edit1: se eu usar ../ para voltar invés de ./ dá o erro **failed to open stream: No such file or directory** em qualquer diretório

Answer (score 1):

Suponha a seguinte hierarquia de pastas:

```
raiz
  pasta1
    arquivo1.php
  pasta2
    arquivo2.php
  index.php
```

Se você estiver dentro do arquivo `arquivo1.php` e quiser fazer um require para o arquivo `index.php` voce deve fazer `require_once '../index.php'`.

Se você quiser fazer um `require_once` de dentro do arquivo `index.php` para o `arquivo1.php` você deve fazer `require_once './pasta1/arquivo1.php'`.

Essa organização vai falhar se houver inclusões multiplas, como por exemplo, arquivo1.php incluindo index.php e index.php incluindo arquivo2.php.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é você utilizar a constante mágica `__DIR__`, segundo o manual ela contém:

> O diretório do arquivo. Se usado dentro de um include, o diretório do
>   arquivo incluído é retornado. É equivalente a dirname(**FILE**). O
>   nome do diretório não possui barra no final, a não ser que seja o
>   diretório raiz.

Dessa maneira fica mais fácil você se localizar já que a referencia passa a ser sempre o caminho relativo ao arquivo que você está editando.

No caso de uma estrutura:

```
/index.php
   /model/model1.php
   /controller/controller1.php
```

Dentro de controller1.php se você quiser incluir o arquivo model1.php ficaria:

```
include(__DIR__ . "/../model/model1.php");
```

Comment: O problema é que usando o DIR eu não consigo voltar pastas

Comment: Warning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjetoBusca\view../controller/EmpresaControlador.php): failed to open stream

Comment: Consegue sim, desculpa... esqueci a barra no final.